# Google Maps Web API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is the link below a valid web api for google maps

http://cbk0.google.com/

I use that link to get a xml values for certain location(lat and long) to check if there is a web view available.

For example:
http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=xml&ll=22.33419,114.145635

If that link is valid. It is free to use it? what I mean here is if it has limit on how many times is allowed to access to that web service. I saw this page https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage#usage_limits stating that only 1000 is limit for 24 hours. Is it applicable for that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage limits apply to the following Maps APIs as already answered in [Which Google Maps APIs have usage limits?](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits):

- Google Maps JavaScript API
- Google Static Maps API
- Google Street View Image API
- Google Maps Directions API
- Google Maps Distance Matrix API
- Google Maps Elevation API
- Google Maps Geocoding API
- Google Maps Geolocation API
- Google Maps Roads API
- Google Maps Time Zone API